# String with error:EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

AppDelegate has a parameter called user,

and user has two parameters called userId & departmentId.

I just want to access my WebService use the ASIHttpRequest API,

but before I send the request,

there is error EXC_BAD_ACCESS with in this code:

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSString *userId = appDelegate.user.userId;
    NSString *departmentId = appDelegate.user.departmentId;
    NSLog(@"xxxxx:%@",userId);//this can log 29
    NSLog(@"xxxxx:%@",departmentId);//this can log 17
    NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetAnnouncement?userId=%@&departmentId=%@&pageIndex=%@&pageSize=%@",userId,departmentId,1,10]; ***//ERROR***
```

The userId's value is 29 and the departmentId's value is 17,

then I change code to:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetAnnouncement?userId=%@&departmentId=%@&pageIndex=%@&pageSize=%@",userId,departmentId,1,10]];//also the same error
```

There is also the same error...

and I dont know why, so pls help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two argument to `stringWithFormat:` are not objects therefore you should not use the format specifier `%@` instead use `%d`

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetAnnouncement?userId=%@&departmentId=%@&pageIndex=%d&pageSize=%d",userId,departmentId,1,10]
```

Answer (score 1):

The last two format specifiers have to be %d to print/format an ordinal decimal number. %@ expects an object and tries to call its -description method, which fails for normal numbers (like 1 and 17) as object pointers. I'm surprised why the logging worked.

So the correct format string should be:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetAnnouncement?userId=%@&departmentId=%@&pageIndex=%d&pageSize=%d",userId,departmentId,1,10];
```